# How to set a base class fields with Immutables and the Egg pattern

Tags: java, builder, radix, egg

I'm using Java's https://immutables.github.io/ and am having trouble with a base class and settings its fields once.

I have Immutable objects that make use of the Egg pattern to share fields, for example:

```
interface HousingBase {
  int streetNumber();
  String streetName();
  int zip();
}

@Value.Immutable
interface House extends HousingBase {
  long lotSize();
}

@Value.Immutable
interface Apartment extends HousingBase {
  int apartmentNumber();
}
```

The problem is my code constructs these objects from a set of the `HousingBase` fields, and I end up with duplicate code, for example:

```
public ImmutableHouse toHouse(HouseLocation location) {
  return ImmutableHouse.builder()
    .setStreetNumber(location.number())
    .setStreetName(location.street())
    .setZip(location.zip())
    .setLotSize(location.size())
    .build();
}
public ImmutableApartment toHouse(ApartmentLocation location) {
  return ImmutableApartment.builder()
    .setStreetNumber(location.number())
    .setStreetName(location.street())
    .setZip(location.zip())
    .setApartmentNumber(location.complex())
    .build();
}
```

What I really want is some way to set the `HousingBase` fields, so that those are defined once. Like this:

```
public ImmutableApartment toHouse(ApartmentLocation location) {
  return setBaseFields(ImmutableApartment.builder(), location)
    .setApartmentNumber(location.complex())
    .build();
}

private Builder setBaseFields(Builder builder, Location location) {
  return builder
    .setStreetNumber(location.number())
    .setStreetName(location.street())
    .setZip(location.zip())
}
```

But I can't figure out how to get this working or if its possible with this library.

Answer (score 0):

Generics!

```
private static <B extends Builder> B setBaseFields(B builder, Location location) {
```